# Adding 'unsafe-eval' to existing chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, alasql

I have an existing chrome extension in Chrome store which is being used by many people. Now I added alasql which uses eval function because of which I had to enable `unsafe-eval` in `content_security_policy`.
I wanted to know will this affect existing users somehow ?

Last time I added geolocation permission in permissions and it disabled the extension for existing users. Users had to manually enable it.

Comment: It may be possible to side-step `unsafe-eval` altogether. alaSQL mentions [`module.noParse`]
(https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/d16eaf41d906ba4ecf28db399bc85c85e73f3904/README.md#modulenoparse) in the README. Also see [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader/issues/6#issuecomment-148436784) issue on webpack CSP(Content Security Policy).

Comment: Changing manifest's CSP doesn't introduce new permissions so no warning should ensue.

Answer (score 1):

`unsafe-eval` does not result in user-visible warnings; as such, there will be no automated disabling of the extension upon update.

*However*, this is a big red flag for update review. It greatly increases likelihood that the new version will [trigger manual review](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-listing-08) for your extension.

Comment: can you please suggest what can I do to this, while using alasql.